# Automatic data decimation for old partitions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

We store our timeseries data in a partitioned Postgres table with a 1 month period. The frequency with which new data is received ranges from 30 seconds to several hours. For all partitions except the newest one (i.e. current month) we need only average per day value.

Is it possible to implement some decimation function/trigger/something else that would be automatically called when the newest partition becomes an old one?

Based on comments, **first of all I need a way of listening that the newest partition has been changed**.

Comment: The short answer is yes. The real question is how.

Comment: @gsiems if you said yes, so what is this "API"  in Postgres that let listening changes of newest partition?

Comment: You would need to create a function to do the actual processing and then put it on a monthly job using the tool of your choice (cron, pg_cron, pg_dbms_job, ...).

Comment: @gsiems Is there any best practice how to re-calculate data in a table? I meant should it be a full copy of table's partition or some other approaches? Sorry, if it is a newbie question